# I am getting "You Lose" even when the game is not over in Update method of GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, game-development

I am unable to understand what is wrong with my logic. It seemed to be working all fine until I made some changes in the app in a few method to spot the tortoises moving too fast.

I get a "You Lose" within a few seconds after the game starts and the count goes up. Enemies havent touched my spritenode still it loses out. I am breaking my head for the last 24 hours to fix this issue.

The code is similar to Ray Wenderlich Zombie Conga

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if lastUpdatedtime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdatedtime
    } else {
     dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdatedtime = currentTime
    //println("\(dt*1000) milliseconds since last update")

    //Tartuga.position = CGPoint(x: Tartuga.position.x + 4 , y: Tartuga.position.y)


    boundsCheckTartuga()

    rotateSprite(Tartuga, direction: CGPoint(x:22, y: 300),rotationRadiansPerSdec: 3)


    //stopTartuga()
    mandateFall()


    if lives <= 0 && !game0ver {
        gameOver = true
        println("you lose!")

        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)

    }
```

Comment: Search your code for anywhere you change the value of `lives` and `game0ver`. Somewhere `lives` is becoming 0 or negative and `gave0ver` is false.

Comment: You may want to check when your updating lives. Check how often that's called and why. Obviously that's a requirement for the conditional statement, so I'm guessing that's the cause unless you set gameOver somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srikanth19,

I am noticing 2 different variables gameOver and game0ver in your given code above.
Was that an issue while pasting the question here or have you defined 2 different variables?

If you have not defined 2 different variables then you should ideally get a compile time error.

Note:
If you are not getting a compile time error then there is a high possibility you may have it declared in 2 instances as a matter of copy paste error.

In your declarations check for:
var game0ver: Bool!

and in some other section of your code (assuming you used Zombie Conga code from Ray Wenderlich) you might have used the correct variable and it gave 
var gameOver: Bool!

I have tried Zombie Conga and also referred the code and one reason your condition is getting in is because of the wrong value in the if condition variable....

Please share your declaration section or let me know if you are able to resolve this issue by checking the value in game0ver (and/or gameOver)

Comment: Thank you for quickly noticing the error in my code. This fixed my issue. There were 2 variables, one of them was true and other was false causing this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If, your variables `lives` and `game0ver` are defined in your class (that's how it looks like), use their `didSet` hook to get notified, when they are changed. That way, you can set a breakpoint and also see the caller, i.e.:

```
var lives : Int { didSet { println("lives changed to: \(lives)") } }
```

Eventually you can see whenever `lives` is changed and track down the point in your game when it is set "by accident".